# The Galois Group of $x^n-1$ is isomorphic to $(Z/nZ)^x$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, galois-theory

I think that the problem statement on this practice question is incorrect, but I don't want to assume that.

The statement is: Let F be a field whose characteristic does not divide n. Prove that f(x) = $x^n − 1$ is separable over F and that the Galois group of f is isomorphic to a subgroup of $(Z/nZ)^×$.

Proving that f is separable:
f'(x) = $nx^n-1$ is relatively prime to f(x) since the factors of f' are just n-1 copies of x. If a function is relatively prime to its derivative in a field, then it is separable over that field.

While proving that the Galois group is isomorphic to a subgroup of $(Z/nz)^x$ I ran into some trouble. I think it is just isomorphic to $(Z/nz)^x$ not a subgroup.

My proof is: 
Since f is separable in F, we must have that L the splitting field for f is a subfield of F. Since all splitting fields are unique up to isomorphism we know L $\cong $ $\mathbb Q$[w, $w^2$, ..., $w^n$,] where w is the primitive nth root of unity.

These roots form a cyclic group of order n, and Aut(Z/nZ) $\cong $ $(Z/nZ)^×$
So the Galois Group (which is the group of permutations of the roots) is isomorphic to $(Z/nZ)^×$.

My issue is that it is isomorphic to the multiplicative group itself, not a subgroup and in a followup problem I am asked to construct a field for $x^15-1$ where the Galois group is a proper subgroup of (Z/15Z)$^x$.

Any insight on this would be awesome! Thanks.

Comment: A group is always a subgroup of itself.

Comment: And actually the derivative is $nx^n$ :))

Answer (score 1):

It is true that the Galois group $G_n$ of the splitting field of $x^n-1$
is isomorphic to $(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^*$. That's not so easy
(see for instance Washington's book on cyclotomic fields), but is
is much more elementary to prove that $G$ embeds in $(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^*$.
Given an $n$-th root of unity $\zeta$, $\sigma\in G_n$ maps $\zeta$
to $\zeta^a$ for some $a$, and $\sigma\mapsto a$ is the embedding
you seek. It's more difficult to show it's surjective.

To get a smaller Galois group than say $(\Bbb Z/15\Bbb Z)^*$
take the fixed field of a subgroup of
the Galois group of $\Bbb Q(\zeta_{15})$
but I suppose that would give an extension whose Galois
group was a quotient rather than a subgroup of $(\Bbb Z/15\Bbb Z)^*$.

Comment: Why is it difficult to show it is surjective? for example, for any $a \in \mathbb{Z}_n^*$, we have the automorphism sending $\sigma \to \sigma^a$. So it is surjective as well

Comment: another way to look at this is to realise that $\mathop{aut}(E/F)$ has cardinality atleast $\phi(n)$ and on the other hand, the map is injective to a set $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$ of cardinality $\phi(n)$. so the map is surjective as well

Comment: @permutation_matrix any chance you ever figured out why it's difficult to show surjectivity? It seems obvious, but there's no way it can be that easy because it's supposed to be a hard theorem that the nth cyclotomic polynomial have degree phi(n)

Comment: @NathanLowry, As I mentioned above, for any $k \in \{1,2,3,4. dots n-1\}$ satisfying $(k,n)=1$, I have the automorphism $\sigma_k$ which is defined on the generator $\psi$ of $\mathbb{Q}(\psi)$ as $\sigma_k(\psi)=\psi^k$ and hence for any $k \in (\mathbb{Z}/n{\mathbb{Z}})^x$, I have one preimage $\sigma_k$ and hence it is surjective.

Comment: I wrote up a question last night after thinking on it for a bit. See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4523323. To prove that this map is surjective requires one to prove that any two primitive nth roots of unity have the same minimal polynomial, which is not at all obvious. This is actually most of the content found in Gauss' original proof of the irreudicibility of the cyclotomic polynomials.